# Prove :$|f'(z)|\leq\frac{1-|f(z)|^2}{2Re(z)}$ if $f:V\to D$ $V=\{z:Re(z)>0\}$ and D is the unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove :$|f'(z)|\leq\frac{1-|f(z)|^2}{2Re(z)}$ if $f:V\to D$ $V=\{z:Re(z)>0\}$ and D is the unit disc
I've thought about it for a couple of hours and I've got no idea...
I didn't learn mobius transformation

Comment: Consider the Möbius transformation $\psi:V\to D$ defined by $\psi(z)=\frac{z-i}{z+i}$ and then precompose $\psi^{-1}$ with $f$. Now, apply the fact that for a holomorphic function $g:D\to D$ we have $\big|g'(z)\big|\leq \frac{1-\big|g(z)\big|^2}{1-|z|^2}$ for all $z\in D$.

Comment: There is a way without Mobius?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know, whether there is a way without using Möbius transformation. Wait, maybe someone will post soon if there is any.